# What is the maximum file size for TIniFile?

Tags: delphi, ini, delphi-10.3-rio

My program manipulates an ini file using TIniFile. I've read [TIniFile class has 64kb limit](https://www.thoughtco.com/manipulate-ini-files-from-delphi-1058227) in single section. However, it seems to be working for more than 100kb in my tests. I'm using Delphi 10.3.3 and Windows 10.

Does 64kb limit exist only in old versions of Windows? Or, should I use TMemIniFile to stay safe?

Comment: Always use `TMemIniFile`.

Comment: `TIniFile` itself does not impose any size limits. It is just a wrapper for the PrivateProfile API, so any limits will be in the OS itself. And [according to Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071126-00/?p=24383): "*INI files are limited to 32KB in size*", but that was 13 years ago. Maybe it has been upped since then.

Comment: There seems to be no specific limit to the file size or text retreival size of the winapi function GetPrivateProfileString (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprivateprofilestring) as long as the buffer is big enough. However I do know (maybe in the old days) there was a limit on the buffer allocate inside TIniFile which was used with GetPrivateProfileString... But as this function isn’t very fast (but does perform good enough on smaller files), extensive use on large files is not adviced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, there is no limit to the size of an ini file or the routine `GetPrivateProfileString` (which is used by `TIniFile` to read the data).
But there are some limits and things to consider when using `TIniFile`.

Looking into the code of the `TIniFile` implementation (thank you Delphi), there are several places where `GetPrivateProfileString` is used to retrieve data from an ini file.

In `TIniFile.ReadString` the buffer size is fixed to 2048 (2k) for reading string values.
As all other 'value' requesting routines use this routine to actually read the data from the inifile, it basically limits the buffer size for all those routines.

Second, the `TIniFile.ReadSections` routine uses a starting buffer of 16384 (16k) characters. But when this buffer is too small it uses a dynamic buffer which is based on the file size, so this way you won't run into a buffer problem (but because this actually reads the entire file to estimate the buffer size, this will be very slow with large ini files).

Last, the `TIniFile.ReadSection` routine, which uses an initial buffer size of 1024 (1k). But dynamically allocates a larger buffer when needed. So at this point, there also doesn't seem to be a limit to the (file)size.

**NOTE**: this information is based on Delhi 10.3 and Delphi XE2.
In older versions there we're other buffer allocation strategies...